# How to make my parallel call in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a shop service that updates the status of products that was bought by customers. I want to update the calls at once .i.e run them in parallel but i do not know the best way. Pls any one to help.  I am using Typescript and i do not want to use a loop

tried this
`for ( let i=0;i<10; i++ ) { // make calls }`

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in this question to understand what it is you're actually trying to do.  All I can suggest is that you really need an atomic snapshot of data to know who bought what and when.  So, if this is just for display, cool.  But make sure your server-side code is the source of truth for what is bought, what is in a basket, etc.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can run the calls in parallel using promise all

Look at this example

```
    const allPromise = Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
    
    allPromise.then(values => {
      console.log(values); // [resolvedValue1, resolvedValue2]
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error); // rejectReason of any first rejected promise
    })
```

Input: Promise.all() takes an array of promises as its argument. Each promise represents an asynchronous operation that may or may not resolve successfully.

Concurrent Execution: Once Promise.all() is called, all the promises in the input array are executed concurrently, meaning they start executing at the same time without waiting for each other to complete.

Resolving or Rejecting: While the promises are executing, they can either resolve (fulfill) with a value or reject with an error. The execution of each promise is independent of the others.

Comment: `Concurrent Execution: Once Promise.all() is called, all the promises in the input array are executed concurrently` the promises you pass with `[promise1, promise2]` are already   "running”, `Promise.all` does not have any effect on how they are running and doesn’t start those, it is just a helper to "wait" for those to finish.